# There was a category move error

Tags: magento2

We have been having problem moving Magento 2 category. When we try to re-arrange/ move a category we get the error, "There was a category move error." We have increased PHP execution time out and reindexed Magento 2, but still these didn't help.

Any assistance would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: try this https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/fe1045aef103a9ba937837f888e496780bd8c312

Comment: Hi. I did try your fix but it actually caused many other problems... :)
1- I couldn't find that path in my installation.
2- So I created the path by adding the diffrent folders and file and the content
 app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/category/edit/form.phtml 
3- when I did that it broke the entire website

Comment: @ P. Paul Sorry you misplaced, please check the answer.

Answer (score 5):

i had the same problem and i successfully could solve it but i am not sure that it is the correct solution. let's go to the solution ...

first of all i explain the problem first:
imagine i have 1 main category and it has 6 sub-category and i want to move one of the sub-category to out of the sub-category so it become another main category.

[image]

solution :
find the sub-category's ID and the main category's ID that you want to move the sub-category under it.
then open the PHPMyAdmin(OR what ever Your DataBase Administration tool is) section and go the related Database and go to the "catalog_category_entity" Table.

[image]

find the sub-category's ID in the "entity_id" column and change the "parent_id" column's value to to the main category's ID that u want to move the sub-category to it.

[image]

save the table and drag and drop it again. that's it.

[image]

**final result** ;-)

[image]

if it doesn't work for u just let me know, so i can help u.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the help. I will try that and let you know as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

There can be **many reasons, one of the possible reasons**, is here, I solved it this way.

If Categories are created programmatically, category position will be either zero or allotted same to all categories.

Check ***`postion`*** column of table ***`catalog_category_entity`***, postion of each category should be different. If any 2 child-category of same parent is same than it will be not movable with each other.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me the error was thrown caused by the fact that moving the category would create 'duplicate urls'.

I went in the database to the url_rewrite table and deleted the custom-type rewrites. Make sure to take a backup before doing so.

```
    DELETE FROM `url_rewrite` WHERE `entity_type` LIKE 'custom'
```

Then You can move the category. Finally ran bin/magento indexer:reindex in the CLI

Comment: but I not have any record with entity_type` LIKE 'custom' 
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'produits-hightech/connectique-adaptateurs-connecteurs/casque-usb' for key 'URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID' in /var/www/html/magento1/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:91

Answer (score 0):

Please try below

root/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/category/edit/form.phtml

Around line number 34

```
<form id="category_edit_form" action="<?php echo $block->getSaveUrl() ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Replace with

```
<form id="category_edit_form" name="category_edit_form" action="<?php echo $block->getSaveUrl() ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

root/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/category/tree.phtml

around line number 472

```
$('form .messages').html(data.messages);
```

Replace with

```
$('[name="category_edit_form"] .messages').html(data.messages);
```

Make sure remove cache , set proper permission , run setup:upgrade before check.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Krishna-- Thank you so much for the support. I have changed/ replaced the line in the first file (form.phtml), but the second file "tree.phtml" was already the same so I didn't changed/ replace anything in it. I cleared the cache and ran "setup:upgrade" then tried again. I didn't get the error message anymore, which was a good sign, but the category were not moved. I think the issue is close to being resolved. :) Any other tricks? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please open the Dev mode to see the detailed errors

Answer (score 0):

1 ) First Go to Exception error and Check for error details.

2 ) Sometimes Your columns are missed from 'field list', if the issue is related to field list then simply run this command.
bin/magento indexer:reindex

Your issue will be resolve.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the indexing mode to Manual indexing before moving categories .
Once categories are moved , do reindex and you can also set back the indexing mode to reindex on save
Thanks